# FInd buses between any stops, MySql query

Tags: mysql

I am creating Bus route finding app where user can find buses between any stops.

My database structure is given below.
But i am unable to find buses between stations, for example one bus a running from station A - Station D. But i am finding station A - station B, no result showing.
please help me to write correct query.

```
CREATE TABLE `buses` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bus_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `buses` (`id`, `bus_name`, `cid`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 'BUS 1', 4, '2023-08-03 06:56:56', '2023-07-27 11:02:05'),
(2, 'BUS 2', 8, '2023-08-03 06:56:59', '2023-07-29 02:32:30');

CREATE TABLE `bus_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `bus_category` (`id`, `cname`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(4, 'NMMT', '2023-07-28 02:34:00', '2023-07-27 08:39:02'),
(5, 'MSRD', '2023-07-28 02:34:05', '2023-07-27 08:39:09'),
(6, 'ST-M', '2023-07-28 02:34:05', '2023-07-27 08:39:09'),
(7, 'MHRY', '2023-07-28 02:34:05', '2023-07-27 08:39:09'),
(8, 'MSEERT2', '2023-07-29 08:02:10', '2023-07-29 02:32:10');

CREATE TABLE `bus_routes` (
  `route_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bus_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start_station_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `end_station_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `departure_time` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `arrival_time` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `bus_routes` (`route_id`, `bus_id`, `start_station_id`, `end_station_id`, `departure_time`, `arrival_time`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 4, '1:00 PM', '2:00 PM', '2023-08-03 07:16:06', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(2, 2, 4, 6, '02:00', '3:00', '2023-08-03 07:16:44', '2023-07-31 07:01:05');

CREATE TABLE `bus_stations` (
  `station_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `bus_stations` (`station_id`, `name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 'A', '2023-08-03 06:57:57', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(2, 'B', '2023-08-03 06:58:02', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(3, 'C', '2023-07-22 15:22:53', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(4, 'D', '2023-07-22 15:22:53', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(5, 'E' '2023-08-03 06:58:11', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(6, 'F', '2023-07-22 15:22:53', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');

CREATE TABLE `bus_stopovers` (
  `stopover_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `route_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `station_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stop_time` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `bus_stopovers` (`stopover_id`, `route_id`, `station_id`, `stop_time`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(0, 1, 1, '1:00', '2023-08-03 07:41:27', NULL),
(1, 1, 2, '1:02', '2023-08-03 07:13:45', NULL),
(2, 1, 3, '1:05', '2023-08-03 07:13:54', NULL),
(59, 1, 4, '1:10', '2023-08-03 07:15:51', NULL),
(61, 2, 5, '2:15', '2023-08-03 07:15:51', NULL),
(62, 2, 6, '3:00', '2023-08-03 07:15:51', NULL);
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    b.bus_name,
    bs_start.name as start,
    bs_end.name as end,
    bs_station.name as stop,
    s.stop_time
FROM bus_routes r
JOIN buses b ON r.bus_id = b.id
JOIN bus_stopovers s ON r.route_id = s.route_id
JOIN bus_stations bs_start ON r.start_station_id = bs_start.station_id
JOIN bus_stations bs_end ON  r.end_station_id = bs_end.station_id
JOIN bus_stations bs_station ON s.station_id = bs_station.station_id
WHERE bs_start.name="A" AND bs_end.name="B"
ORDER BY  r.departure_time;
```

Comment: You are searching on start and end stations only, not in the stations between them

Comment: Please help me to  write query to find buses between stations.

Comment: You need to search via the stopovers table.

Comment: Provide desired output for your sample data with detailed explanations. Provide precise MySQL version. PS. https://dbfiddle.uk/GUietzfh (misprints fixed). PPS. `DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'` is not reasonable default value for TIMESTAMP NOT NULL column. Use `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, check does the column was updated by `created_at = updated_at`.

Comment: Desired output : bus_name, bus_station.name and bus_stopover.stop_time

Comment: Please note: if this is a homework question, this approach (e.g. querying mysql directly, without preparing the data) might work. If you actually want to create an app, this approach will not scale at all (as the possible combinations explode: there is probably a valid bus route from new york to new jersey via san francisco), and you might want to have a look at some graph algorithms.